# unable to set useridentity in Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using Singlestepauthentication.

In the first screen I am calling client. connect with the challenge handler added to it.

this works fine but when I call the below method

submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, options);

I am getting following error

```
An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project _MFP]AuthAdapter/submitAuthenticationFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project _MFP]Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm 'AuthRealm'. The application must logout first. FWLSE0101E: Caused by: [pro
```

This happens for when I am trying set it for the first time.

I also tried below code in adapter it doesn't throw error, but it doesn't add the new userid also...

```
WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", null);
WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);
```

Please help

Comment: You did not supply enough code. Provide your actual implementation of the challenge handler and adapter.

Comment: Ok please check this question for the whole code....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789992/calling-setactiveuser-throws-error    I dint get the answer so created it short and asked in a different way