# How to update(change ) UserIdentity in IBM Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to change the useridentity with different credentials. It gets successful login with realm but the new Userid is not getting updated in Mobilefirst console. Console still shows the old userID.

I am using the following code.

```
function submitAuthentication(username, password){

         userIdentity = {
                userId: username,
                displayName: "sample", 
                attributes: {
                    foo: "bar"
                }
        };


        WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", null);
        WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity); 

        return { 
            authStatus: "complete" ,
                result: "Success"
        };
//  }
}
```

I just saw below error at android client side, challengehandler class/handleChallenge method

```
 07-12 07:14:34.265 13001-13078/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.shouldFailOnChallengeCancel()' on a null object reference


07-12 07:14:34.266 13001-13078/com.mfp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient$InvokeProcedureRequestListener.onFailure(WLClient.java:1376)
07-12 07:14:34.266 13001-13078/com.mfp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.triggerUnexpectedOnFailure(WLRequest.java:337)
07-12 07:14:34.266 13001-13078/com.mfp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.requestFinished(WLRequest.java:295)
07-12 07:14:34.266 13001-13078/com.mfp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:52)
07-12 07:14:34.266 13001-13078/com.mfp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
07-12 07:14:34.266 13001-13078/com.mfp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
07-12 07:14:34.266 13001-13078/com.mfp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-12 07:14:34.333 13001-13007/com.mfp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 66.075ms
```

The below was the issue

activeRequest(WLRequest object) in BaseChallengeHandler was null while calling submitSuccess(); in ChallengeHandler
That was the reason I was getting above error . I was not able to resolve the main issue but I was able to get ride of above mentioned error.

The below place was the place where activeRequest was not given right value.
As request.getOptions().isFromChallenge() is always true so the value of activeRequest was not set to right value.Its null after this.

So I made fromChallenge as false.

```
public void startHandleChallenge(WLRequest request, T challenge) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(!request.getOptions().isFromChallenge()) {
                if(this.activeRequest != null) {
                    this.requestWaitingList.add(request);
                    return;
                }

                this.activeRequest = request;
            }
        }

        this.handleChallenge(challenge);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you attach your project or at least the challenge handler code and the full code of the adapter?

Comment: I have put the code for a different issue but its the same code. Please check the following link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789992/calling-setactiveuser-throws-error

Comment: Were you able to find any solution .. I have been stuck on this from two days.